# Redirect URL issue with Gmail Api and using OAuth in Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I would like to send an email using Gmail OAuth protocol from Python. For some background, the general process of my program takes user input, creates an image, then sends an email.  In theory the program could be sending hundreds of emails at some point.  The issue that I ran into is when I tried to retrieve a token for OAuth, I received an Unauthorized redirect url error. The app has not been verified nor do I have a G Suite Admin account, but every tutorial I walk through make no mention of this. The only redirect urls I have enabled are `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground` and `http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback`, which are both in the client_secret.json file I download from the credentials page on google developers.

Here is what I have:

```
import base64
import httplib2
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

# Path to the client_secret.json file downloaded from the Developer Console
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

# Check https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'

# Location of the credentials storage file
STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')

# Start the OAuth flow to retrieve credentials
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http()

# Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
# This is where it fails.
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)

# Authorize the httplib2.Http object with our credentials
http = credentials.authorize(http)

# Build the Gmail service from discovery
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

# create a message to send
message = MIMEText("Message goes here.")
message['to'] = "my_email@gmail.com"
message['from'] = "my_email@gmail.com"
message['subject'] = "your subject goes here"
body = {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}

# send it
try:
  message = (gmail_service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=body).execute())
  print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
  print(message)
except Exception as error:
  print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```

Comment: So what you would need to do is to add the `redirect_uri` in the OAuth consent screen and after that [redownload the *JSON* file with the credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362621/oauth2client-clientsecrets-invalidclientsecretserror-missing-property-redirect). Try to do that and confirm if you still having trouble with this error.

Comment: Where is the OAuth consent screen? Because the instructions you laid out is what I did as my question states.

Comment: Does your client secret have  a `redirect_uri` field? Try to add it in there and check if you can get past that error. There are some question around the same error too and maybe some already solve your issue [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362621) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312994/google-api-oauth2-0-quickstart-py)

Comment: Okay that worked, but now I get an Authorization Error about how the redirect url:  http://localhost:8080/ does not exist. Yet I provided http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback and http://127.0.0.1:8887/oauth2callback as redirects.

Comment: You need to actually use the [`run_local_server`](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html#google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.run_local_server) to make that page exist. That would handle all the token interaction as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Has this worked for you? Are you following any guide/tutorial for making this happen?

Comment: I have been working on some other things and trying to solve it. Apologize for the delay. I am only trying to ask questions if I truly get stuck and then respond with positive feedback.

Comment: So I have been following various guides that I eventually all get stuck at. I am new to the development world and confused on what parameters to plug in. I kinda see how the process works in what you sent, but I am still having an issue with the redirect_uri/l? Also, some places say I need a G Suite account. I am a little frustrated. Can we do this with the requests package?

Comment: Have you actually followed the [quickstart in python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) for drive? This seems a more sensible place to start. You can see there the way your code should like in terms of authorization.

Comment: That is exactly what I followed and did. It worked at the time.

Comment: My suggestion then would be to get the same code for authentication and change only the file `credentials.json` to the one from the GCP project. Remember to include the relevant API and the correct scopes

Comment: Do I have to verify my app or pay for a G suite account? I have done what you said above, but keep running into the same unauthorized access error. Let me edit the question to show what I have.

Comment: Have you configured the OAuth screen in your GCP project?

Comment: On the Credentials page, I have an OAuth client id and secret, with the above redirect uris. On the OAuth consent screen the app is not verified as I do not have a homepage or privacy policy. Like I said, it is not really a Web app, but every tutorial has you sign up for an "Other" type of app.

Comment: Being a web app or not is irrelevant. You need to create a OAuth screen, otherwise you could access data from users that have not authorize you to handle data. You can try this without using the consent screen using service account. Also take a read into this [post](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914).

Comment: So it seems like I do need to get a Homepage and Privacy Policy. Figured that out and sent in the app to be verified.

Comment: Right there in the post it says that you don't need to verify your app for personal use. Is just that you would get an unverified warning.  This is applicable for less than 100 users. So you can still use it.

Comment: Well it does say your app needs to be verified if you use a sensitive scope...Your app uses any of the sensitive or restricted scopes to request Google User Data. Google did tell me it did not need to be verified, but their documentation is quite poor. And frankly I am no closer than I was a week ago. Have you done this before?

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed in greater details in the comments.

Basically when you create an app that interacts with google services the user needs to accepts the scopes that your app will have. This means you need to create a [Oauth Consent Screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en).

So you go to your project in [Google Console Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com), in there choose **Api & Services > OAuth consent screen** or go to [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent). To create that OAuth Consent Screen you will be prompted with two options:

- **Internal:** Only for G Suite accounts, your app will be only accessible by members of your organization
- **External:** The only option for NON G Suite accounts, if you access "powerful" scopes the app will need to be verified, if not it will be tagged as unverified.

For your case (which seems personal use/development) just go ahead and deal with unverified app choose **External**.

[image: OAuth Consent Screen creation]

You can see that in fact google is pointing out that I need verification but on creation I get prompted with a screen explaining that my app is an [unverified app](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)

[image: OAuth Screen]

Use this only for personal use (it has a 100 users cap).